# What would affect the rate of recharge of a lead-acid battery?

Tags: electrochemistry, kinetics, electrolysis

I am trying to perform an investigation regarding lead-acid batteries and would like to specifically look into the recharging mechanism. However, I realised that this might be quite difficult since the recharge equation is 
$$\ce{2PbSO_4 +2H_2O->4H^+ +2SO_4^2- + Pb + PbO_2}$$
Would anything except for the voltage supplied affect the rate in which the charging takes place (or the current through the electrodes)? For example, would changing the concentration of the electrolyte affect the rate of recharge?

EDIT: I was just looking at the equation and thought that if I increased the concentration of the electrolyte, which is the sulfuric acid, it would actually cause the equilibrium to shift left, meaning that the current would be lower with higher concentrations of sulfuric acid. Is this correct?